# Difference in sending HTTP status codes from php

Tags: php, web-services, http

what is the difference from setting the responce status in php

header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

and

header("Status: 404 Not Found");

What is the difference from the client point of view (aka browser or a client implementation for RESTful WS). I understood that the second one has to do something with CGI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found` is *the* HTTP response code, it's what allows clients to determine whether a request succeeded or not.

`Status: 404 Not Found` just sets an extra header field called `Status` with the value of `404 Not Found`. It has no intrinsic meaning, it's like setting `header('Foo: Bar')`. It may mean something to somebody, but it's [not officially specified what it should mean](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). *The* HTTP response code will be a normal 200 OK.

There seems to be a special case when running PHP through FastCGI. Apparently you can't set the `HTTP/` status directly when invoking PHP with this method. Instead you have to set this unofficial header, which will be converted to a real `HTTP/` code before it's send back to the client (apparently a limitation of how PHP can talk to the web server when invoked via CGI). In all other cases, it'll just be send as-is (with no meaning) and the real HTTP response code will be 200 OK.
That's what I could gather from the [description in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) at least, I've never had to use this. Also, you're insane if you run PHP through CGI, so hopefully nobody needs this in this day and age. ;o)

Comment: thanks. i find it quite strange that the HTTP response code is sent like this from php. Do you know if for example i write "HTTP/1.0 404 Found no doggy" is it going to be recognized as the 404 response or is it analyzing the whole string?

Comment: @user PHP only pays attention to the beginning of the string. If it starts with `HTTP/`, it takes the whole thing as the HTTP response code. And yes, you *can* send `HTTP/1.0 404 Found no doggy`. Most clients will probably even accept this, since they probably only look at the number, not the text.